# Example of DNSServiceRegister and DNSServiceBrowse for iOS5 Bonjour through bluetooth communication

Tags: iphone, c, ios, networking, bonjour

I am looking for an example code that shows how to use `DNSServiceRegister` to register a service with a Bonjour and an example code that shows how to correctly use `DNSServiceBrowse` to discover services.

I am aware of the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/dns_discovery_api/Articles/registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002478-SW2), which I have read and there is no examples there.

What I essentially would like to do is to use does low level classes to broadcast and search for services through a bluetooth network and then use [`GCDAsyncSocket`](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to comunicate b/w them.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the need to use bluetooth with Bonjour in iOS5, and I finally ended up building my own little mini-framework around the DNSService* APIs, which I put up on github ([HHServices](https://github.com/tolo/HHServices)) in case it might help others who were frustrated about the limitations in iOS5.

Forgot about MYNetwork though :) That's probably a good choice too!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how low level you're looking for, but for most uses the `NSNetService` and `NSNetServiceBrowser` classes should do what you need in terms of mDNS advertising / discovery. Check out the comprehensive [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002736). I've found the [Cocoa for Scientists article](http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxviii-bonjour-and-how-do-you-do) gives a pretty good rundown of how everything works, too.

Advertising & discovering services using bonjour and the means you use to connect them together are orthogonal concerns; if you want to use `GCDAsyncSocket`, berkeley sockets or whatever else, as long as device X knows about a service on device Y via mDNS, establishing a socket connection is your problem ;)

Bluetooth PANs will support multicast broadcast but expect it to be slower then a conventional Wifi / ethernet-based IP network.

Comment: The tricky part about my question is that I ask for Bonjour over bluetooth for iOS5. As of the latest iOS version apple discontinued supporting bluetooth networking for its NSNetService as stated in ([Technical Q&A QA1753](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1753/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011315))